Who develops low level hardware drivers?
I have spent a significant amount of time reading about kernel device programming.
One thing I'm fairly confused on is who is responsible for developing the lowest level interface software?
Ex: if I want to use GPIO I use the GPIO sub system and write my kernel interrupt driver using the register interrupt functionality.
Who is responsible for developing those low-level software interfaces that talk directly to the hardware? Ex the GPIO interrupt stuff?

The general answer is whoever wants to. Assuming the goal is to get drivers into the Linux kernel, there’s an additional requirement of being able to get the drivers reviewed, approved, and merged, although the kernel has a “staging” area where the barrier to entry is low.
Existing drivers’ maintainers are listed in the MAINTAINERS file in the kernel source tree; that will tell you who is responsible for a given driver.
